# Java Agent crash while call run api of JavaAccessBridge.dll

Tags: java, c++, dll, accessibility, java-access-bridge

I want to programmatically enable Java assistive technology. For that I follow the steps below:

1) Create Java agent for inject in any running java application VM.

2) Create the C++ DLL with three API calls for enabling assistive technology.

JavaAccessBridge-64.dll

```
runDll
```

JAWTAccessBridge-64.dll

```
jawtGetComponentFromNativeWindowHandle
jawtGetNativeWindowHandleFromComponent
```

3) My .net application will call this C++ DLL for capturing Java screen.

I found fatal error while calling run API in Java Access Bridge.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=4196, t
id=10404
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_40-b43) (build 1.7.0_40-b43)

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.0-b56 mixed mode windows-amd64
compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client vers
ions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\MAHEND~1.GAJ\AppData\Local\Temp\\hs_err_pid4196.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

Comment: Got the soluction

Comment: If you solved the issue, please post your solution as an answer.